# Wordpress landing page redirecting to live site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I am using WordPress for my application.

`http://localhost/ranbar` this is my local URL. When I enter this URL its automatically redirects to my live site. `http://*******/ranbar/`.

If I enter inner page url its redirecting correctly.
For e.g :

```
http://localhost/ranbar/certifications/

http://localhost/ranbar/about-us/

http://localhost/ranbar/contactus/
```

I have searched in entire folder but there is no live URL (`http://*******/ranbar/`) in my files. Even have searched in Database and .htaccess files.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you tried changing site_url and home_url in wp_options table?

Comment: @FaisalSarfraz Yep, Have changed everything

Comment: try deleting .htaccess file and saving permalinks and your home page from settings.

Comment: Tried this now. Oops!. Still goes to live site. When I press Visit site from admin side.

Comment: if it goes to live site from admin side then this means that either its being overridden from code or your home url and site url is still different in Settings page

Comment: Also let me know if you're using any redirection plugin, Can you list plugins name here ? that you're using

Comment: ACF, Akismet, Custom Post Type, Gravity Forms, Intuitive Custom Post Order, WP DB migarete., WP migrate db pro media files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have shifted a live site to your local machine, do this:

in your database check table `wp_options` find `home_url` & `site_url` and check if they have your local url or live if it is live url then simply change it with your localhost url.

Comment: Have changed from all places. Even have given find all by giving live site. But there is none of words is there in my file and also in database. Have only local URL's

Comment: just for test login into your dashboard go to permalinks and just click save/update button then clear your cache and check.

Comment: Have changed this also. Have tried new one. Have changed the landing page as about us and fornt page as home and when I visit about us It goes to live site. When I visit front page its works. So what ever the landing page comes It redirects to live site

Comment: Go into database, change the two feilds in wp_options. go to site settings in Wordpress admin panel make sure the url is set correctly.

Comment: show us your landing page if you can, may b your existing live url

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to do is add define URL directives in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Yep, Already changed in config file. But still I cant access only my home page or landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading php version 5.4 to 5.6 will solves this problem.

We have developed our application in 5.6, But our live server has the version as 5.4, thats why we have faced the error like this.

Hope it will help someone also.